# Check the render method of pressable in react native

Tags: react-native

```
         <Pressable>
           <Text>hi</Text>
          </Pressable>
```

i am getting an error

×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(PressableWithoutRef)`.

Comment: Make sure you import the component correctly.

Comment: import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button, Pressable
} from "react-native"; this is what i have imported

Comment: Hmm, the problem could be with your react-native version as the Pressable component is available at >= 0.63.